# "Error: you attempted to set the key `latitude` with the value `37.785834` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, state, immutability

I'm using the `navigator.geolocation` API in React Native to set the user coordinates as part of the component state, which the `MapView` is supposed to use as the `region` prop, and running `getCurrentPosition()` throws an error.

I'm not sure how to fix this. The error says this is an immutability issue, although I made sure I used `let` and `const` where they're supposed to be.

This is my initial state:

```
this.state = {
      data: {
        name: "Nie powinieneś tego widzieć.",
        address: "Wyślij zrzut ekranu tego widoku do nas na stronie dokosciola.pl w zakładce Kontakt.",
        url: "https://dokosciola.pl",
        coords: {
          latitude: undefined,
          longitude: undefined,
          latitudeDelta: 0.00922 * 1.5,
          longitudeDelta: 0.00421 * 1.5
        },
        hours: ["8:00", "10:00", "12:00"]
      }
};
```

This is how I use the geolocating API:

```
locateUser = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        let state = this.state;
        state.data.coords.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        state.data.coords.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.setState(state);
        console.log(this.state);
      },
      error => Alert.alert("Ups!", `Wystąpił wewnętrzny błąd:\n${error}`),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 5000 }
    );
};
```

I run the `locateUser()` function before mounting the app, so:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.locateUser();
}
```

This is how I use the `MapView` component from `react-native-maps`:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          initialRegion={this.state.data.coords}
          region={this.state.data.coords}
          mapType={"mutedStandard"}
        >
          {data.map(element => {
            return (
              <ChurchMarker
                coords={element.coords}
                key={element.id}
                onPress={() => this.update(element)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
</View>
```

`ChurchMarker` is a precooked `Marker`, also from `react-native-maps`, and `data` - a simple array of objects, mocking a potential API response:

```
[
    {
        id: string,
        name: string,
        address: string,
        url: string,
        coords: {
            latitude: number,
            longitude: number
        },
        hours: string[]
    },
    ...
]
```

I expect the `MapView` to focus on the user coordinates as the app mounts, but the error I specified in `locateUser()` executes, with the following message:

```
Error: you attempted to set the key `latitude` with the value `37.375834` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.
```

After that there's also a warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `region.latitude` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

and the same for the longtitude. This means the state didn't update.
Any fixes to this? What am I implementing wrong?

Comment: Reminder: are there any immutable objects?

Comment: @zixuan there aren't any, I didn't use any `const`s anywhere. I used `setState()`, and didn't modify the state directly. Everything seems okay.

Comment: Ok, what about the API? You defined `state` to `this.state` which has to use `setState()` and then you directly changed the longtitude and latitude from `state`'s longtitude and latitude.

Comment: @zixuan you mean I should directly do `setState` with the `position` coords, without doing `let state = this.state`? Isn't that how you normally update state? By cherrypicking the fields I want to modify?

Comment: Of course. Look, it is actually not necessary to do that and "isn't that how you normally update state", no, we normally update state by this: `this.setState({a: "foo"})`.

Comment: So what do you mean? What did you suggest there?

Comment: I suggest that you try to update `this.state` with the object way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is clearly described in the error message: **you attempted to set a key on an object that is meant to be immutable**.

When you write `let state = this.state`, you are creating a reference to `this.state`, which is immutable.

So when you try to assign a new value to `state.data.coords.latitude` you are mutating the state object, which is illegal.

Instead you should refactor your code in two steps:

1. Simplify the state object to reduce nesting (get rid of the `data` layer):

```
this.state = {
    name: "Nie powinieneś tego widzieć.",
    address: "Wyślij zrzut ekranu tego widoku do nas na stronie dokosciola.pl w zakładce Kontakt.",
    url: "https://dokosciola.pl",
    coords: {
      latitude: undefined,
      longitude: undefined,
      latitudeDelta: 0.00922 * 1.5,
      longitudeDelta: 0.00421 * 1.5
    },
    hours: ["8:00", "10:00", "12:00"]
}
```

2. Create a `newCoords` object and set it with the correct values, then overwrite `state.coords` by using `setState`:

```
locateUser = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const newCoords = {}
        newCoords.latitude = position.coords.latitude
        newCoords.longitude = position.coords.longitude
        this.setState({ coords: newCoords })
      },
      error => Alert.alert("Ups!", `Wystąpił wewnętrzny błąd:\n${error}`),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 5000 }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You must always update Your `state` with the object way. In Your case You can try this:

```
locateUser = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({
         data.coords.latitude: position.coords.latitude,
         data.coords.longitude: position.coords.longitude 
       });
       console.log(this.state)
      },
      error => Alert.alert("Ups!", `Wystąpił wewnętrzny błąd:\n${error}`),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 5000 }
    );
};
```

Or if for the new `state` You want to manipulate the current `state` You must use the functional way of `this.setState`

For more information read this part of [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

Good Luck :)